# Problema al migrar tablas con Laravel (Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed)

Tags: laravel

[image: Error en terminal al momento de migrar]

Migracion de la tabla alumno

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('alumno', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Migracion de la tabla nota

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('notas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('curso');
        $table->string('alumno_id');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('alumno_id')
                            ->references('id')->on('notas')
                            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Comment: no debería ser `on('alumno')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

los detalles son:

1. El campo que servirá como llave foránea debe ser `integer` y no `string` como lo tenías
2. Además de tipo `unsigned`, el otro detalle es que la llave foránea debía estar referenciando a la tabla alumnos pues de ahí obtiene la **llave primaria**

**MUESTRA DEL CÓDIGO**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('notas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('curso');
        $table->integer('alumno_id')->unsigned();    
        $table->foreign('alumno_id')
              ->references('id')->on('alumno')
              ->onDelete('cascade')
              ->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

> Siempre considera que el campo que servirá de llave foránea
>   reconocerlo como `unsigned`, pues este método te ayudará a que esa
>   columna no quede con registros de `ids` negativos.
>
> También te hago la observación, en tu tabla alumno la llave primaria
>   es de tipo entero y auto `incremental` pero en tu tabla notas la llave
>   foránea la declaras como `string` y eso es incorrecta desde que no son
>   del mismo tipo de datos; así que por favor mejor declaralos como
>   enteros y `unsigned`.